# AJAX chat client for Cisco WebEx Connect

Tags: xmpp, chat, cisco, webex

I'm working on creating a chat client that is supposed to interface with Cisco's WebEx Connect IM. I'm using Cisco's CAXL library and I got it to work with gchat, which seemed a reasonable XMPP start-point. However, now I'm totally stuck. What services do I need to register for at Cisco to get access to a BOSH / XMPP endpoint that I can use with the chat client? How would I go about this? The project has an unlimited budget but I can't figure out what to buy -- totally unfamiliar with Cisco's enterprise jungle.

I've contacted WebEx support but no response yet. We don't have a real account with them yet so support seems hard to come by.

Thanks for any direction! ~Charlie

Answer (score 1):

The right path to get support for CAXL is to go to the [Cisco Developer Network](http://developer.cisco.com/) (CDN), then click on Develop with Jabber, Develop and Test, Get Started - Hosted Deployment.  At the top, there's a link for community support and to contact the CDN team, which has escalation paths that... end back up with me. :)

You just need an account on [WebEx Connect](http://www.webex.com/connect/) to move forward.

Comment: Haha! That's awesome about the escalations. Thanks for the response! I signed up and got a strange \@aol.com account, and it doesn't seem to work with the same approach I used to get an @gmail.com (gchat) account working (pointing my CAXL client at the jappix.com/bind BOSH endpoint). Is there something wrong with that? Does webex connect have their own BOSH endpoint that I can connect to? Still not quite sure how this BOSH / XMPP stuff works :(

Thanks!

Comment: Crud.  I forgot that the free accounts still go to aol.  Please try asking a question on CDN to see if you get a response.  If not, ping again, and I'll figure out a way to contact you directly.